# User/Feed Graph Api don't show 'tags' and 'place' when I use 'object_attachment' parameter

Tags: android

I'm developing a Application use Graph Api to post Feed of User.
I used Tool and Support to post user feed follow attach image below:
After posting feed, My post feed don't show **tags friend** and **tags location**.
They just show when I remove fields **object_attachment**

Pls help me for this issue! Thanks